# Combine the results of two tables in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables :

TMP_Turnover

```
Year Code   | CODE_DEVISE   | CODE_AFFILIATE|   Period  |Turnover
```

TMP_Outstanding

```
Year Code   |CODE_DEVISE    |CODE_AFFILIATE |Frequency  |Period |Outstanding
```

How to comine the results of the tables in one table
Main

```
 Year Code  |CODE_DEVISE    |CODE_AFFILIATE |Frequency  |Period |Outstanding|Turnover
```

I tried using union but it dosen't return the best results, I'm a newbie with SQL SERVER.

Comment: Maybe you should study up on SQL, this is very basic stuff.

Comment: just a suggestion  JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Use join. For beginner level in sql, check w3schools site, they have good tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT Join AS below:

```
SELECT
    TT.YearCode,
    TT.CODE_DEVISE,
    TT.CODE_AFFILIATE,
    TO.Frequency,
    TT.Period,
    TO.Outstanding,
    TT.Turnover
FROM TMP_Turnover TT
LEFT JOIN TMP_Outstanding TO ON TT.YearCode=TO.YearCode 
    AND TT.CODE_DEVISE=TO.CODE_DEVISE 
    AND TT.CODE_AFFILIATE=TO.CODE_AFFILIATE
    AND TT.Period=TO.Period
```

Comment: how to get the results from table TMP_Outstanding that dosen't exist in table tmpturover?

Comment: can you please also show data, so i can prepare query for it OR you can just change table order in left join

Comment: You have to just play with LEFT Join and where conditions